# Airflow to pass config from UI manual run

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

is there any way to pass JSON config from manual DAG run (the one from `dag_run.conf['attribute']` to KubernetesPodOperator?

Tried to use the Jinja template on the templated field in YAML, but got an error, `dag_run is not defined`.

```py
task_parse_raw_data = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace=NAMESPACE, 
        image='artifactory/image:tag',
        service_account_name='airflow',
        cmds=["sh", "/current.sh"],
        arguments=[ {{ dag_run.conf['date']}} ],
        ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the Jinja expression in quotes like so:

```py
arguments=[ "{{ dag_run.conf['date'] }}" ]
```